# ajax call always return error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use my github api, but it always return error.
the same thing is happening for https://api.meetup.com/2/cities also.

I am very new to ajax please help.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

  $('.image').text("loading......");
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://api.github.com/users/vivekpradhanC",
    success: function(data){
      alert("enter");
      $('.image').text(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.responseText);
      alert(ajaxOptions);
    },
    datatype:'jsonp',
  });


});
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the error message is... i'd guess that it's relating to cross-site scripting

Comment: xhr.responseText is not returning any value

Comment: I just checked the fiddle, and its working perfectly. Please check you html/javascript, for correct parameters or syntax. It is going in success function of your ajax, so why should it go to error function?

Comment: Yah. I agree with @AjitKumarSingh Downvote for working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting a remote URL in ajax, this might not be allowed because of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy, you maybe not allowed to access this URL throught Ajax.

Check this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more info.

Comment: I don't understand why do you say *maybe not allowed to access this URL throught Ajax.* OP's code is working without an error message. Can it be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: Maybe!! since this depends on the site he is requesting, and since there is no error message specified, then this is the most probable case..